# Procmon is crashing when saving the boot logs

Tags: windows, sysinternals, procmon, process-monitor

I have been trying to analyse a registry activity during booting.

So thought of using procmon for boot logging. I enabled the boot logging, restarted the system. Now when i started the procmon it asked me to dump the boot log collected .

When i tried to save the file, after sometime with progress of 7% it crashed with the famous error log "`The instruction at "0xXXXXXXXX" referenced memory at "0xXXXXXXXX", The memory could not be "written". Click on OK to terminate that program`".

Best Regards,

Saurav

Comment: Known bug, use an older version (http://forum.sysinternals.com/crash-while-saving-boot-log_topic32293.html)